# GPU not detected

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, drivers, nvidia

So, I am trying to configure my nvidia driver, installed via AppCenter, and it's not been listed in Nvidia X Server Settings as you can see here:

[image]

And i'm getting this error when I launch it by the console:

[image]

I've already did some search and tried to reinstall the driver from ppa, from .run downloaded from nvidia website and from cli 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall', but all i get is the same case. I even reinstalled the elementary itself, but nothing changes, can someone please help me? If there's any issue in my request, please tell me so I can clarify myself, thanks.

**EDIT:**

So, I thought it might help if I said what I'm trying to do here..

I'm looking to play CS:GO, and I just moved to Linux, on Windows, I got about 80 fps with everything in medium/high, and on Linux, I got about 40 fps with every video option in very low/low, i think it's because the GPU was in 'performance mode' on windows, set by nvidia control panel, and by what I've found on foruns, the nvidia x server settings is suppose to allow me to do that.

I don't know if that info is usefull, but it's better than none information hehehe.

Comment: What's your video card model?

Comment: Nvidia GeForce 930MX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Terminal displays errors communicating with your display, please check two things.

1. Go to `System Settings` > `Displays` and check if your display has been correctly detected by the system.
2. Type in terminal: `nvidia-smi`

Are the driver version and GPU model shown in the output table? If not, try this procedure to reinstall the driver (worked fine for my NVIDIA card):

1) Clean the system from any NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

2) Add NVIDIA PPA (if you haven't already added it earlier):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers

sudo apt-get update
```

3) Install the correct NVIDIA GPU driver and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver430
```

(this is the correct driver version for your 930MX GPU, as stated [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/148435/en-us))

```
sudo reboot
```

5) Check if the driver has been successfully installed:

```
nvidia-smi
```

6) Check if your system is free from the obsolete open-source "nouveau" driver:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau
```

If the output is negative for *nouveau*, then all is well with your installation.

Comment: So, i did the steps to reinstall the driver and looks like it's installed, but, when I typed nvidia-smi on terminal, i got this output "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running." (same output before reinstall)... And now nvidia x server settings is completely blank, it doesn't have even the two options that was there before...

Comment: PS. When I start nvidia x server settings typing on terminal "nvidia-settings", I'm getting this message:

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:1666): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:48:44.240: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 19:48:44.242: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 19:48:44.242: PRIME: is it supported? no

Comment: If you get the error message "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver", try disabling Secure Boot Control in BIOS.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! FINALLY!!! Before creating this post i did a lot of search, to see if i could do it by myself, but i didn't find anything about the secure boot, i would never think about it, so, thank you soooooo much for all your help, you really saved me...

Comment: @LucasZorzi did you had any problems with black screen after unlock your screen? or slow resume also?

ps: i encoutered the same problems that you mentioned above, i have a gtx 1650