# NVidia Drivers problems

Tags: graphic-drivers, nvidia

Hello I just installed Elementary OS 5.0 Juno. After the installation, from the app center I installed NVidia 3.40 and then clicked to install NVidia 390. Later I realized I can only used either 3.40 or 3.90, so I clicked to install 3.40 again, but it gave me errors and stuff.
Thinking it's because of the 3.90 driver installed, I click to uninstall NVidia Drive 3.90 from the app center, but nothing happens.
 
I restart my PC and when I load Elementary OS it goes black screen. So I guess I messed up something in the graphical drivers.

I tried to use sudo apt --fix-broken install and it gives me some kind of errors I don't know how to fix.
[image]

I tried to purge NVidia packages also. And hoping to install but I still get the errors while installing
[image]

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: The following may delete apps or change settings of programs that you've already installed. Make sure to have a backup of the important files.
Open a Terminal and execute the following:

First delete all nvidia drivers with `sudo apt autoremove nvidia*`

Then install the correct driver for your system with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

---

If any of this breaks your desktop, you can install it with `sudo apt install elementary-desktop`

Comment: The command `sudo apt autoremove nvidia*` and then a reboot solved my problem on Elementary OS 6 Odin! Thank you!

Comment: Great! But please remember that you're using the Noveau drivers (open source) now. If you need a bit more performance you might want to install the propietary drivers. Depends a lot on your GPU.

Comment: Yop, but then I've installed the nvidia driver again from the Elementary OS AppCenter. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

If your elementary OS installation is fresh and hasn't been meticulously fine-tuned for many hours, I'd suggest reinstalling it; this could really be a much quicker and cleaner solution than trying to unscramble messed video driver dependencies.

After the clean elementary OS re-installation, I'd also suggest installing the correct driver for your video card from NVIDIA PPA instead of using the default driver that ships with the system.

- To allow installing from PPAs, execute `sudo apt install software-properties-common`
- To define the correct driver version for your NVIDIA card, go [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
- To install the driver from NVIDIA PPA, see [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/gpu-not-detected).

Comment: Your answer is good but, it's bad advice to install a PPA when you don't really need it. The drivers available on Appcenter are good enough and for most hardware it won't make a difference to install an older version instead of the cutting edge one. Plus a newbie would probably prefer to just do `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` than going into all that trouble.

Comment: Well, what can I say? Not so long ago my own PC couldn't work normally with 'good enough' drivers from elementary AppCenter. So I tried this method being a newbie myself, and it made my elementary installation finally work. As to adding PPAs, as far as I know, NVIDIA's PPA isn't some random piece of junk and is trusted enough.

Comment: That may be because you have new hardware or your specific hardware had an issue resolved on newer versions of the driver. But it's not typically needed.

Comment: Typical or atypical, thing is, it worked in real life. Thanks for downgrading.