# Empty desktop after login

Tags: release-juno, system-installation, greeter

It's pretty self-explanatory, I have installed elementary alongside windows 10 on my Asus Zenbook ux580ge and after logging in I get an empty desktop with just the background image and the cursor (which I can move)

What do I do?

*Which I can move for a limited period of time, after that it just freezes

Comment: Freezing cursor may indicate video driver issues. What's your video card model?

Comment: Nvidia GTX 1050ti

Comment: When you launch AppCenter ('Installed' tab), are NVIDIA drivers listed there in 'Drivers' section?

Comment: I can't launch AppCenter, thats the thing, I can't do anything beside entering my password to log in. Once I log in my profile everything on the screen disappears and the only things I see are my mouse cursor and the background image. Is there any way I can check/install these drivers using the terminal?

Comment: Yes, there is. Short version: execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Othewise, try the long version: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/19424/17985

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out and let you know how it goes

Comment: I have nvidia driver installed and it works, but sometimes I have exactly the same issue - dekstop image and the mouse pointer only - the mouse can be moved but you can do nothing more. Sometimes if I wait too long, plank and everything appears, but sometimes it is impossible even to reach the console login through ctrl+alt+f2 for example. And there is no problem when i swithch prime-select to Intel instad of Nvidia. It looks like the problem is with the driver, try to reach console login (ctrl+alt+f2), log in using your credentials and execute into console `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Working! now I can use the actual OS but my second monitor won't get recognized anymore... opening another thread